# Get ADF Pipeline JSON from C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to get the entire JSON of an ADF pipeline (both v1 & v2) from C#

I could see documents that provide details abut creating pipelines from C#, unfortunately I am not sure of the right method/endpoint to perform this operation in C#.

```
var client = new DataFactoryManagementClient(cred) { SubscriptionId = subscriptionId };

var factory = client.Factories.Get("", "");

var pipeline = client.Pipelines.Get("", "", "");
```

Unfortunately that doesn't provide me what am looking for, I believe the JSON are formatted as C# objects in `factory` and `client`

Am I right with the above statement ? Will I have all the JSON details in C# objects?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Data factory exposes rest api and SDK which you can call for both V1 and V2 which gives you the pipeline result in json .

For example : Below api will give you the list of pipeline in json format for one Factory:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factoryName}/pipelines?api-version=2018-06-01
```

same set of operation you can do it using SDK too by using below method:

```
public static Microsoft.Rest.Azure.IPage<Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory.Models.PipelineResource> ListByFactory (this Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory.IPipelinesOperations operations, string resourceGroupName, string factoryName);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datafactory.pipelinesoperationsextensions.listbyfactory?view=azure-dotnet

Similarly if you are looking for one particular pipeline , you can call below API:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factoryName}/pipelines/{pipelineName}?api-version=2018-06-01
```

same set of operation you can do it using SDK too by using below method:

```
public static Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory.Models.PipelineResource Get (this Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory.IPipelinesOperations operations, string resourceGroupName, string factoryName, string pipelineName, string ifNoneMatch = null);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datafactory.pipelinesoperationsextensions.get?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_DataFactory_PipelinesOperationsExtensions_Get_Microsoft_Azure_Management_DataFactory_IPipelinesOperations_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_String_

As you can see all the SDK method returns below c# model object which you can serialize in JSON format using NewtonsoftJson library.

Hope it answer your question. Let me know if you any assistance .

Comment: Almost this is what I was looking for, saw the documentation but unfortunately I didn't get it. Thanks Mohit.

But the DataFactory and Pipelines returned from the SDK doesn't have a property to determine if they are V1/V2, could you throw some light on that Please?

Thanks :)

Comment: So far to what I understand the above sdk only supports V2

Comment: SDK is available for both V1 and v2. V2 is in preview which you can use it by belo command : # Be sure to include the most recent version from the NuGet package page
dotnet add package Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory --version 0.2.0-preview and  here is ti for V2 Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactories  Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/data-factory?view=azure-dotnet